# why android webview get the wrong width on the HTML5 when the application boots

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

**Using Android emulator genymotion (800*1280）**，it is wrong to get the window.innerWidth. the description is flowing:

**When the android app has installed,I set js language in the event window.onload=function(){alert(window.innerWidth)}   to get the viewport width, but the answer is 320（this is wrong）, and then I click a button, the triggeld event $(button).click(function(){alert(window.innerWidth)}) ,but the answer is 602 (the is right).**

Of course `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">` has append to the HTML5 head.   It is no problem when I tried with the Chrome mobile debugger (800*1280).the answer is 800.

```
<button value="click me get the width"/>
<script>
 //we all know window.innerWidth can get the viewport width
window.onload=functon(){
    alert(window.innerWidth)
}//get the wrong answer 320
$(button).click(function(){
    alert(window.inerWidth)})//get the right answer 602
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tested it on device ?

Comment: Yes, but the answer is 320.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272989/android-webview-getwidth-window-innerwidth
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304489/webview-returns-bad-window-innerheight

Comment: Which versions of Android are you testing on and which version of Android API are you building with (target SDK).

Comment: the api is 19 ,thank you

Comment: @Rayon Dabre, Hi, Thank you for the website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304489/webview-returns-bad-window-innerheight
it said that This is because Javascript executes before WebView's View related initialization. And Android WebView returns a 320x240 default value to JS. But
`$(function(){
   alert(window.innerWidth)   // 320
   alert(window.screenWidth)  //800     **why can get the 800?**
})`
as you said, why window.screenWidth can get the right screen resolution 800?

Comment: Try running the same code in deviceready event and see what results you rae getting ?

Comment: After some reading,another solution has occured. in java code, we can use  `new Handler().post(new Runnable(){ @Override  public void  run(){ webview.loadUrl("...")}});`  add it to QueueMessage,and delayed the js to executed

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

My use case was to render the website at a custom resolution, not necessarily the device's resolution.

I couldn't get the desired results with `WebView` whatsoever. `AdvancedWebView` worked in the first attempt.